# Random clicks on page for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, html, testing, angularjs, touchscreen

I would like to test my web-page to find any flaws (broken paths). My web will work with touch screen interface and it is important to check whole page area. I am definitely 'tabula rasa' concerning auto testing web. My first idea is to random clicks on the pages when `document` is ready. I can imagine that if we do such auto-clicking enough time it will go every path on the page. Is it possible to do that with some nice Javascript snippet?

---

My page has more like clickable areas defined with Angular's ng-click. Not sure if this makes things more complex for suggested solutions.

Comment: How about http://validator.w3.org/checklink?

Comment: It would be easier to just find all links and elements with an onclick property on the page and then activate them. You might want to look into something like Selenium http://docs.seleniumhq.org . Randomly selecting points on the page to click is a terrible idea, if it's truely random there's no promise that it will click all of the page elements no matter how long it runs.

Comment: @sushain. No chance with validator. This is not public page.

Comment: The problem with doing it in Javascript is the same-origin policy :/

Comment: @Pherric. I agree. Random is random, but could somehow simulate touching in every place.. Do you mean searching onclick's and bulid the tree of clicks? Could be nice.

Comment: BTW. I am not searching for nothing fancy at this point.

Comment: Can you use something like http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/ running the site locally? (seems pretty supported: https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker)

Comment: @sushain. Not sure. My clicks are controlled by clickable onclick'ed <div> elements.

Comment: I understand what you mean, perhaps you should try it. I doubt there is a good JS method due to the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe instead of random clicks just extract all the links that is on the page and test each one individually. For example if you extract them like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    doSomethingWithThisLink(links[i].href);
}
```

My idea is that you can call an AJAX function with the link and see if it returns OK or not :-)

I made a small demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/33Sz9/

Hope this helps!
Jen

Comment: The problem with this is that if the link is not on the same domain (all external links), the AJAX request will violate the JavaScript same-origin policy and not work.

Comment: My page has more like clickable areas defined with Angular's ng-click. So can't use that.